# Formal group operation

Tags: logic, universal-algebra

This exercise appears in An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions by George M. Bergman.

> By "the set of all terms in the elements of $X$ under the formal group operations $\mu, \iota, e$" we shall mean a set $T$ which is
>
> - given with functions
>     $\mathrm{symb}_T : X \to T, \mu_T : T^2 \to T, \iota_T : T \to T,$ and $e_T : T^0 \to T$,
>     such that
> - each of these maps is one-to-one, their images are disjoint, and $T$ is the union of those images, and
> - $T$ is generated by $\mathrm{symb}_T(X)$ under the operations $\mu_T, \iota_T,$ and $e_T$; i.e., it has no proper subset which contains $\mathrm{symb}_T(X)$ and is closed under those operations.

Now, the exercise asks whether the third condition follows from the first two. I am inclined to believe that it does not, but I am not sure how to proceed with a proof.

A question which may or may not be relevant is also whether these axioms forbid a term from being the *image of a term, which is also the image of another term...*, continuing like this and never reaching $\mathrm{symb}_T(x)$ for some $x \in X$. I am used to *bottom-up* definitions where terms are given by induction on "depth" or "length", but I can't get my head around this presentation.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the second condition, since $T$ is the union of the images? If $T' \subset T$, then $T'$ doesn't contain the images of the functions, because $T$ is the union of those images...

Comment: As I understand it, such a set $T'$ would not need to contain the images of the functions, only the images of the restrictions: $\mu_T$ restricted to $T'^2$, $\iota_T$ restricted to $T'$, and contain $e_T(*)$.

Answer (score 2):

Terms can be visualized via "term trees".
The term trees in the language of groups over the set $X$ can be described
as finite, rooted, labeled trees satisfying the following conditions.

Each node has degree at most $2$. (Degree = number of children.)

A node of degree $2$ is labeled with the symbol $\mu$
(denoting multiplication).

A node of degree $1$ is labeled with the symbol $\iota$ (inverse).

A node of degree $0$ is labeled with an element of $X$
(generator) or with
the symbol $e$ (identity).

Let $T$ be the set of these labeled trees. Define $\textrm{symb}_T$
so that it
maps $x\in X$ to the 1-node tree with label $x$. Define
$e_T$ so that it
maps the single element of $T^0$ to the 1-node tree with label $e$.
Define $\mu_T$ so that it
maps the pair $(s,t)\in T\times T$ to the
tree in $T$ with root of degree $2$ labeled $\mu$,
whose left child is the root of a subtree equal to
$s$, and whose right
child is the root of a subtree equal to
$t$.
Define $\iota_T$ so that it maps $s\in T$ to the
tree with root of degree $1$ labeled $\iota$,
whose child is the root of a subtree equal to $s$.
It is not hard to show that all three of Bergman's
conditions hold for the data $T$, $\mu_T$, $\iota_T$, $e_T$.

Now to address the problem: "Does
the third of Bergman's conditions follow from the first two?"

Answer: No.

Let $T'$ be a set of *possibly infinite*, rooted, labeled trees
defined by the same conditions. To make sure this is a set, restrict to those possibly infinite trees where every node
has a finite path to the root. Conditions 1 and 2 still
hold for $T'$, but Condition 3 does not. The subset of $T'$ generated
by $\textrm{symb}_T(X)$ under the operations is just the subset of finite labeled trees.

Comment: Could you explain how there can be rooted trees with nodes potentially not having a finite path to the root? I indeed needed a way to add infinite trees in such a way that 1. we ended up with a set (not too many) 2. they are labelled so that the one-to-one conditions are met (enough different ones).

Comment: Under the definition of "tree" found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(set_theory), some nodes need not have a finite path to the root. If you use the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure), which is what I intended (although I allow the trees to be infinite), then all nodes will have a finite path to the root.

Comment: I am very confused, because from what I understand, what they call "paths" seem to be "branches", so they are either infinite or end on a leaf (their example of a fully infinite binary tree is made up of nodes which can all reach the root by "going up" finitely many times). I did see the example of $\omega + 1$ which shows that sometimes there is no "transitive reduction" for the underlying graph of a poset (in which case the only possible way to turn it into a graph yields a length one "path" from the root to any other node).